# Connecting to Heroku Postgres Database using Navicat

Tags: database, postgresql, ssl, heroku, navicat

I'm using Navicat to connect to Postgres running on my Heroku application.
I entered the correct Host, Port, Database Name, User, Password, but I'm getting the following
connection error:

[image]

I searched for the solutions to this error, and I modified **pg_hba.conf** by adding this line:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

also I uncommented the following lines in postgres.conf:

```
listen_address = '*'
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100       # (change requires restart)
```

I restarted Postgres, but Navicat still gives me the same error.

I thought the issue could have been the SSL settings, so I followed this manual:
http://www.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/navicat_datamodeler/win_manual/SSLCert.html

Nevertheless, I am getting the same error.

Can anyone assume what the problem is?

Comment: Are you able to connect through any other client?

Answer (score 5):

When you're setting up the Connection Properties, after you've filled out the information under the General tab (Host Name/IP Address, Port, Default Database, Username, and Password), click on the SSL tab.

Check `Use SSL` and under the dropdown list titled `SSL Mode` select `require`.

Then test the connection. Your connection should be successful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems you have same issue I do on Mac OS version of Navicat. I tried everything to fix also, and pgadmin was working just fine. The solution was to create a new connection as somehow this connection is corrupted and there is nothing you can do to fix it seems in the UI that I could find.

Comment: Funny; I'm trying to do the same thing.  What did you finally end up doing?  I can't seem to connect no matter the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try connect using SSL. Works for me.